# Iphone interface builder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, interface, interface-builder

hey all my question about how the developers makes their interface the buttons, slider, segmented control and other is any program can make those thing ? and then import it to interface builder ? my brother is a graphic designer and he work a lot a 3d modeling he can make all those thing in 3ds max, maya or cinema 4D but how to tell the interface builder about each element like this is a slider or this is a button on so on. or their is a specific program ?

cheer

Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you won't find such a utility anywhere. All those UI elements you find in iOS (or any other GUI, for that matter), need to be individually coded, with rasterized images or vector graphics or whatever to make them look nice, but the behaviour needs to be written in code (unless this has already been done, and you only need to tell the UI element which graphics to use, as it is the case with UIButton in iOS, for example).